# This error shows when writing my code : ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I want to zoom in on the scatter plot but the following function when used shows that scatter requires x column to be numeric. I was watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pY9EwZ02sXU to help with my project.

```
    def plot_region(x_bounds, y_bounds):
           slice = points[
           (x_bounds[0] <= points.x) &
           (points.x <= x_bounds[1]) & 
           (y_bounds[0] <= points.y) &
           (points.y <= y_bounds[1])
          ]

           ax = slice.plot.scatter("x", "y",s=35, figsize=(10, 8))
           for i, point in slice.iterrows():
                     ax.text(point.x + 0.005, point.y + 0.005, point.word, fontsize=11)

    plot_region(x_bounds=(4.0, 4.2), y_bounds=(-0.5, -0.1))
```

This error was shown when I tried to run my code:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-3606d96f6cad> in <module>
----> 1 plot_region(x_bounds=(4.0, 4.2), y_bounds=(-0.5, -0.1))

<ipython-input-54-4232c0d6bc17> in plot_region(x_bounds, y_bounds)
  7     ]
  8 
----> 9     ax = slice.plot.scatter(x=1,y=1,s=35, figsize=(10, 8))
 10     for i, point in slice.iterrows():
 11         ax.text(point.x + 0.005, point.y + 0.005, point.word, 
 fontsize=11)

 c:\users\ninet\pycharmprojects\minorproject\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, **kwargs)
 1442             ...                       colormap='viridis')
 1443         """
 -> 1444         return self(kind="scatter", x=x, y=y, s=s, c=c, **kwargs)
 1445 
 1446     def hexbin(self, x, y, C=None, reduce_C_function=None, 
 gridsize=None, **kwargs):

 c:\users\ninet\pycharmprojects\minorproject\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
 736         if kind in self._dataframe_kinds:
 737             if isinstance(data, ABCDataFrame):
 --> 738                 return plot_backend.plot(data, x=x, y=y, 
 kind=kind, **kwargs)
 739             else:
 740                 raise ValueError(

 c:\users\ninet\pycharmprojects\minorproject\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py in plot(data, kind, 
 **kwargs)
 59                 ax = plt.gca()
 60             kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
 ---> 61     plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
 62     plot_obj.generate()
 63     plot_obj.draw()

 c:\users\ninet\pycharmprojects\minorproject\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in __init__(self, data, x, y, 
 s, c, **kwargs)
 928             # the handling of this argument later
 929             s = 20
 --> 930         super().__init__(data, x, y, s=s, **kwargs)
 931         if is_integer(c) and not self.data.columns.holds_integer():
 932             c = self.data.columns[c]

 c:\users\ninet\pycharmprojects\minorproject\venv\lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in __init__(self, data, x, y, 
 **kwargs)
 868             y = self.data.columns[y]
 869         if len(self.data[x]._get_numeric_data()) == 0:
 --> 870             raise ValueError(self._kind + " requires x column to 
 be numeric")
 871         if len(self.data[y]._get_numeric_data()) == 0:
 872             raise ValueError(self._kind + " requires y column to be 
 numeric")

 ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric
```

Can someone please help me figure out this problem on what I should do to rectify this error?

Comment: Hi & welcome to SO. Your questions is much more likely to get answered if you show code can be reproducible. Can you add some data to your question? And also, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I tried to run the code but 'points' is not defined. Can you please share a working example?

Comment: I have taken my code from this github link <https://github.com/llSourcell/word_vectors_game_of_thrones-LIVE/blob/master/Thrones2Vec.ipynb>.

Answer (score 0):

What code are you doing this in? Like what site? I think you could try and turn this into HTML format. Also try turning this:
plot_region(x_bounds=(4.0, 4.2), y_bounds=(-0.5, -0.1))
Into:
plot_region(x_bounds=(4.0, 4.5), y_bounds=(-0.5, -0.0));

Comment: I am doing this code on jupyter notebook. This video has its code in github <https://github.com/llSourcell/word_vectors_game_of_thrones-LIVE/blob/master/Thrones2Vec.ipynb>, if that helps